# How to Determine the Sort Order of an NHibernate ICriteria Object?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria

What is the best way to retrieve the list of Orders added to an ICriteria object using the AddOrder method? I believe this will have to be accomplished using Reflection, but what to reflect on?

The purpose of doing this is that I would like to pass the sort order back to the UI so an indication of the sort order can be provided to the user.

Comment: mmm .. since you add the Orders using AddOrder, you surely know what Orders were added. Why not return an object containing a list of fields(that were added in the query) or whatever ?

Comment: @sirrocco - unfortunately the Orders are added in different methods at different times, so I would have to pass this list of fields through to quite a few methods...certainly not out of the question but not quite what i was hoping for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var impl = session.CreateCriteria<User>().AddOrder(Order.Asc("Id")) as CriteriaImpl;

foreach (CriteriaImpl.OrderEntry entry in impl.IterateOrderings())
{
Order order = entry.Order;
    // now you have the order and you can either parse it : "propertyName asc" 
                                                         or "propertyName desc"
    // or you can check it out in debug, it has a few protected fields that you could reflect. 
    // not sure if there's another way.
}
```

Comment: Cheers m8, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Excellent, I needed this info as well, and I only found it on Stack Overflow, thanks sirrocco